# Sencha Touch 2 and floating, flexing panels

Tags: iphone, sencha-touch, panel, floating

I'm having a problem with Sencha Touch 2 and vbox flexing. Here is my code for the Panel (modified for simplicity, real Panel is much more intricate but this is what it boils down to):

```
Ext.define('risbergska2.view.Test', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
xtype: 'test',


config: {
    title: 'Test',
    iconCls: 'home',

    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: 'vbox',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    flex: 2,
                    style: 'background-color: #f90;'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    flex: 1,
                    style: 'background-color: #9f0;'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    flex: 1,
                    style: 'background-color: #0f9;'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    flex: 2,
                    style: 'background-color: #90f;'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

})

And here is my Main.js:

```
Ext.define("risbergska2.view.Main", {
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
requires: [
    'Ext.TitleBar',
    'Ext.Video'
],
config: {
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'homeloggedinview'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'myview'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'programview'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'socialview'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'aboutview'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'test'
        }
    ]
}
```

});

My app.js:

```
Ext.application({
name: 'risbergska2',

requires: [
    'Ext.MessageBox'
],

views: ['Main', 'HomeLoggedIn', 'My', 'Program', 'Social', 'About', 'Test'],

launch: function() {
    // Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element
    Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();

    // Initialize the main view
    Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('risbergska2.view.Main'));
},

onUpdated: function() {
    Ext.Msg.confirm(
        "Application Update",
        "This application has just successfully been updated to the latest version. Reload now?",
        function(buttonId) {
            if (buttonId === 'yes') {
                window.location.reload();
            }
        }
    );
}
```

});

If I run this code and go to the Test-panel, nothing is showing. I want it to show (in the test case) four different containers with four different colors in them, the top one and the bottom one being twice the vertical size of the middle ones.

Is this not the way to get that result? Where have I gone wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused as to why this question has anything to do with Flex.

Comment: The problem is directly in relation to the "flex" property for Panels in Sencha Touch. It has nothing to do with Adobe's Flex. I'm sorry for your confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set layout : 'fit' for risbergska2.view.Test

```
Ext.define('risbergska2.view.Test', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
xtype: 'test',


config: {
    title: 'Test',
    iconCls: 'home',
    layout : 'fit',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: 'vbox',
            items: [
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. I've tried it before and while I thought it should work according to Sencha's documentation, it doesn't. Perhaps something else is wrong with my code... But I just can't see where I've missed something. This seems so trivial also so it really annoys me!

Comment: I test your risbergska2.view.Test as main application view it works fine if add to config layout : 'fit'. For test you can put you view in viewport. In app.js    launch: function() {
        // Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element
        Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();

        Ext.Viewport.add({
            xtype : 'test'
        });
    } Is console output empty?

Comment: I have added the Test panel as the last element in my TabPanel which should be the same thing. For testing purposes I changed my launch panel to my Test panel as You suggest here, but it still shows me nothing. I mean the panel loads, but it has nothing showing in it, just a grey background and the bottom TabPanel is gone, since that gets loaded in my Main.js.

Comment: Code from app.js added for clarification.

Comment: Sorry, missed one question. Yes, console has no errors or warnings. It is completely empty.

Comment: I tried create new application with your code,all works fine. Try delete other tabs from "risbergska2.view.Main" and leave only         {
            xtype: 'test',
            layout : 'fit'
        } It  helps you localize error

Comment: Oh wow, I actually got it to work now! When I put layout: 'fit' in my Main view instead of in the actual Test xtype it worked. I don't really grasp why that is, if I specify layout: 'fit' in the xtype I should get the same results, right? Anyway, it works now so thank You very much for your help!

Comment: When you define view you should specify layout in config section, when you create you put layout to options